# How to write the file in CP10000 encoding (java)?

Tags: java, file, encoding

I need to convert .csv file from CP1252 to CP10000 encoding. I use next code...

```
    File newFile = new File(inTargetCharsetFolder + File.separator + file.getName());

    try (
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "CP1252"));
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(newFile), "CP10000"))
    ) {

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            writer.write(line + "\n");
        }

        return newFile;

    } catch (Exception e){
        return file;
    }
```

But at the output I get empty file. If I use, for example UTF-8 instead CP10000, all is fine.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: You need to close your readers and writers.

Comment: @Kayaman he doesn't. He's using try-with-resources, which closes any AutoClosable.

Comment: Does your OS support CP10000?

Comment: Why are you suppressing the exception?

Comment: @f1sh Oh you're right, the formatting made it unclear.

Comment: @Norbert van Nobelen I don't know. I use Windows. But this code are using on web server (linux), so I think I will be able to open the file at any system.

Comment: Translating the code page uses the underlying available code pages. Check your installed code pages on the webserver (in this case)

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen: java does not internally use OS support, it uses its own classes `sun.nio.cs.ext.*` in `rt.jar` and `charsets.jar` (look with `jar t`). When you output to (or input from) Windows or Linux console then OS support for the encoding/page matters, or for a Unix terminal support by the terminal emulator, but OP here seems to be using disk files. OP: try displaying the exception and you'll see Java doesn't support `CP10000` as an encoding.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I still need to convert it anyway

Comment: Google 'java encoding macintosh roman' finds that `x-macRoman` exists, but I don't know how well it matches the Windows version.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 many thanks. You've helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working "MacRoman"

```
File newFile = new File(inTargetCharsetFolder + File.separator + file.getName());

try (
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "CP1252"));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(newFile), "MacRoman"))
) {

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        writer.write(line + "\n");
    }

    return newFile;

} catch (Exception e){
    return file;
}
```